# More Precise and Higher Frequency Scheduling in Google Cloud functions / Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like a cloud function to be called precisely every 15 seconds exactly when the server clock is at 15 sec intervals i.e. at `XX:XX:00` `XX:XX:15` `XX:XX:30` and `XX:XX:45`. I tried using cloud scheduler but I am having the following issues:

1. Using unix-cron the highest frequency is every minute. In addition using `* * * * *` does not seem guarantee that an event will happen at `XX:XX:00`, but rather every minute from when I start the the task.
2. My cloud function can still be called by a `post` call which could really mess up my clock. The temporary solution I have for this is putting in a really long hash like SH256 into the header and requiring it to run the cloud function. This can slow things down a lot, originally I wanted to use RSA or ECC but that would make things even slower I think, so for now I just have a string compare against a long SH256 string. I hope there's a better / more efficient way around this.
3. The aforementioned issue with scheduling at `XX:XX:00` `XX:XX:15` `XX:XX:30` and `XX:XX:45` is also a real pain. The best solution I found is to have the function called once and then sleep and try to sync up to those times. This is supper janky / hacky at best.

Perhaps there is another service within the Google Cloud platform that is more suited to this specific use case? Or another approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

When I need an higher frequency than the minute I use [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) by doing this:

- Create a Cloud Scheduler which trigger each minute my function 1. I set a retry policy on this scheduler
- The function 1 create, for the minute after, the 4 next tasks to run (for example, the function is trigger at 00:00:00, it creates the task for 00:01:00, 00:01:15, 00:01:30, 00:01:45). Cloud task can create delayed tasks
- The task trigger the function 2
- Function 2 performs the business logic